# Getting error due to '\'(escape char) as end of the column values during loading data into snowflake from sql server using COPY activity in ADF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

### I am using ADF copy activity to load data from SQL server to Snowflake, Getting an error during loading to snowflake as
ERROR:

"first error Found character '1' instead of field delimiter ','"

### MY DATA:

c1         c2
rajesh\    1

characher "" is treated as escape character while loading data into snowflake.

At sink side, I have added below 2 file format option and tried different values but it didn't work out.
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD
ESCAPE
Please share any suggestion how to handle this and Appreciate your support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GUI builder for the file format, scroll to the bottom section. In the drop-down boxes, you want to set the "Escape Unenclosed Field" to None. If there are still problems you can also try setting the "Escape Character" to None.

If you're using SQL to create or replace the file format, you want a section like this:  `ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE'`

Comment: HI Greg, Thanks for the replay.  I have tried as you advised but no luck. Please advice me go proceed further

Comment: I see this issue still occurs :(
Does anyone have a solution?