# How to resolve ESCAPE property in ADF Copy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

[image: "additional snowflake options]

We are having issues with a source table column having a value '\' (just slash, nothing else in record data) which seems to mess with snowflake ESCAPE char, I am trying to override that in ADF COPY Sink properties but it is not working..

This is what it generates and run..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE "stg"."abc" URL = 'azure://staging/2b476d30-f166-4f81-ac57-8765bf79f29b/SnowflakeImportCopyCommand/' CREDENTIALS = (AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = '☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺')

FILE_FORMAT = (type = CSV RECORD_DELIMITER = '

' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' ESCAPE = '\\' SKIP_HEADER = 1 NULL_IF = '' ENCODING = UTF8)

COPY INTO "stgdb"."tab1" ( "col1", "col2",,,,,... , "INSERT_DATE", "UPDATE_DATE") FROM (SELECT $1, $2, $52, $53, $54 FROM @"stgdb"."abc") FORCE = TRUE LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES = TRUE ON_ERROR = CONTINUE

DROP STAGE IF EXISTS "stgdb"."abc"
```

Looks like it a bug with ADF not using the property settings?

Comment: Same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409025/getting-error-due-to-escape-char-as-end-of-the-column-values-during-loading?rq=2

Comment: you config of ADF show ESCAPE `^^` if you are using `^^` why have you got snowflake using `\` (as noted via `ESCAPE = '\\'`) surely you want these to be "the same"

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like it a bug with ADF not using the property settings?

In ADF Snowflake Connector For **Additional Snowflake format options** we get only following options as per [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#snowflake-as-sink). the Optins you are using manually will not work
[image]

And regarding Escaping the `\` from the Column value it will escape it if it's in-between the string like `rajesh\h`. If it's at the end of the string like `raj\` it will throw an error as it will also escape field delimiter.

**To resolve this, you need to use two quotes around the string like `'"raj\"'` so it will escape the slash. as Snowflake doesn't provide to use to field enclosed characters you need to manipulate it further**

**My output with sting contains  `\`  is:**

[image]

Comment: But in the document it shows, you can add additionalFormatOptions Additional file format options provided to the COPY command, provided as a dictionary of key-value pairs. Examples: DATE_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT. For more information, see Snowflake Format Type Options.

Comment: In drop down only the mentioned three formats are there. Other formats are not there.

Comment: Right since it has free text entry, it should have supported all thru it